# Recursive Search broken in Nautilus 3.6 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: nautilus, search

I really liked the look and feel of the new Nautilus, so I installed from the GNOME3-team/gnome3 ppa, but now I can't really search - it only finds things directly sitting in the current directory, and doesn't traverse down the file tree. Any suggestions?

Also, the version on the ppa is 3.6.0, but when I downloaded 3.6.1 from the project site and built from source, the same issue occurred.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: This is likely a bug that needs to be reported to the GNOME3 team directly, thanks!

Comment: @user99245 This is actually a desired behavior by many users, do you know how to get it back?

Answer (score 2):

The bug was fixed on Nautilus 3.7.1. [Here is the full list of improvements.](http://worldofgnome.org/nautilus-3-7-1-release-brings-improved-search/)